# Debugging android wear watch and handset at same time

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

Is it possible to debug both an android wear watch app and an android handset app at the same time?

I'm trying to debug sending data back and forth between a handheld device and an android wear watch app and it'd be nice to be able to attach the debugger to both apps at the same time.

I'm running on a physical nexus 4 device and using the android wear emulator on my computer.

Comment: You might get away with being able to launch 2 instance of an IDE and debug one on each (if the system can handle it).  One wirelessly connected via ADB and another via cable.  Otherwise, not sure if you could through one.

Comment: Is this what debugging over bluetooth is for?  It looks like this would require a physical watch right?
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

That's possible of course. In Android Studio you can switch between the connected devices in the Debug Monitor. See the following screenshot:

[image]

Note: It may take a second or two until the messages will appear